# Find net work on the system

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to solve the following problem. If someone can just point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.  I don't have the textbook and online resources are proving to be absolutely worthless.

> A piston-cylinder device containing a fluid is fitted with a paddle
>   wheel stirring device operated by the fall of an external weight of
>   mass 47 kg . As the mass drops by a height of 6.1 m , the paddle wheel
>   makes 10800 revolutions. Meanwhile the free moving piston
>   (frictionless and weightless) of 0.59 m diameter moves out by a
>   distance of 0.70 m
>
> What is the net work for the system if the outside pressure is 101
>   kPa?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Can you [edit your question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/posts/6992/edit) and show us your work?

Comment: Hi NTC, welcome to Engineering SE. Please see [this Meta discussion](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/368) for some more information about getting help with homework problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work that the system does on the atmosphere by pushing the piston outward is just $$W=\int{PdV}$$
From your problem statement, it looks like you have a constant pressure of 101 kPa and a change in volume of $\Delta V=\frac{\pi}{4}(0.59\ \mathrm{m})^2(0.7\ \mathrm{m})=0.19\ \mathrm{m^3}$.  The work done by the system is then $W=(101\,\mathrm{kPa})(0.19\ \mathrm{m^3})=19.3\,\mathrm{kJ}$.

On a side note, the energy added to the system by the falling weight is only $\Delta E=mg \Delta h=(47\ \mathrm{kg})(9.81\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}})(6.1\ \mathrm{m})=2.8\ \mathrm{kJ}$, so either the numbers are wrong or there was some other energy input besides the falling weight.

[This link on expansion work pretty much sums it up.](http://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/howtosolveit/Thermodynamics/ExpansionWork.html)